# Re-format matched items into two columns

Tags: r, cytoscape

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I am not even entirely sure what keywords to use to search for this problem.

I have a list of genes and a list of cell types in which they are found. I want to create a network interaction table to show interactions between the cell types they are expressed in, preferably using Cytoscape which I have been trying to work out for the last day or so, but for now I am just trying to reformat my data, and for that I need to get my cell types into two columns.

An example of my current data for a single gene is below, which is in 4 cell types, but obviously I have several thousand genes in the full table, each of which can be in just one cell type, or multiple (not always 4)

```
    GENENAME                  CellType
     CRYM                     Epithelial 
     CRYM                     Tubule  
     CRYM                     Cardiomyocyte
     CRYM                     Glandular
```

What I want is to reformat the above data to show the linkages between the cell types, i.e. to reformat into something like this:

```
    GENENAME                  CellType1         CellType2
     CRYM                     Epithelial        Tubule
     CRYM                     Epithelial        Cardiomyocyte
     CRYM                     Epithelial        Glandular
     CRYM                     Tubule            Cardiomyocyte
     CRYM                     Tubule            Glandular
     CRYM                     Cardiomyocyte     Glandular
```

Which column each of the cell types ends up in doesn't matter for the further analysis, but it would be good to avoid reverse-duplicates. However I cannot figure out how to reformat the data in this way. Could anyone help?

I believe I should then be able to load data in this two-column format into Cytoscape to create a network analysis, and remove links with very low numbers of genes in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but here I go
Basically first step is to filter the step for each GENENAME, after that I create a loop to gather all the CellType2 and keep appending them.

```
library(dplyr)
CellType <- c("Epithelial","Tubule","Cardiomyocyte","Glandular","Epithelial","Tubule","Cardiomyocyte","Glandular" )
GENENAME <- c("CRYM","CRYM","CRYM","CRYM","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC")

df = data.frame(GENENAME=GENENAME,CellType=CellType)
df_full = c()
for (i in unique(df$GENENAME)){
  df_temp = filter(df,GENENAME==i)
  all_match = c()
  for (k in 1:nrow(df_temp)){
    anchor = df_temp[k,"CellType"] # This is the CellType1
    pair = df_temp[k:nrow(df_temp),"CellType"] # Find all the CellType2
    match = expand.grid(anchor,pair) #Create all combination
    all_match = rbind(all_match,match) #Append result
  }
  all_match = cbind(i,all_match) # Add the GENENAME information
  df_full = rbind(df_full,all_match)
}

result = filter(df_full,Var1!=Var2) #Remove case when CellType1 == CellType2
print(result)
      i          Var1          Var2
1  CRYM    Epithelial        Tubule
2  CRYM    Epithelial Cardiomyocyte
3  CRYM    Epithelial     Glandular
4  CRYM        Tubule Cardiomyocyte
5  CRYM        Tubule     Glandular
6  CRYM Cardiomyocyte     Glandular
7   ABC    Epithelial        Tubule
8   ABC    Epithelial Cardiomyocyte
9   ABC    Epithelial     Glandular
10  ABC        Tubule Cardiomyocyte
11  ABC        Tubule     Glandular
12  ABC Cardiomyocyte     Glandular
```

Comment: Yes this does work, although takes some time to run given it is such a large dataset, thanks.